# Change pointer of pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory, char

I'm trying to write a void function that gets a pointer to a pointer of a string (`char**`) as a parameter, and changes the original char* so it pointed to another string, lets say "hello".

Below is the code I've written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void change_ptr(char **str_ptr)
{
    char hello[] = "hello";
    char *hello_ptr = hello;
    *str_ptr = hello_ptr;
}



int main()
{
    char str[] = "yay";
    char *str_ptr = str;
    char **ptr_to_str_ptr = &str_ptr;
    change_ptr(ptr_to_str_ptr);
    printf("%s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, Im getting the pointer to the pointer of the char* "yay", delivering it to the function, and in the function I'm getting the pointer to "hello", and changes *str_ptr (which is the pointer to the original string) to the pointer to hello. But when I print str at the end, it prints "yay".

What am I doing wrong?

(when I debug with printing the addresses, everything seems fine.)

Comment: You need to print `str_ptr`. Note, however, that `hello` only exists within `change_ptr()`.

Comment: `str` is an array. `str_ptr` no longer points to it (after the call to `change_ptr`, it contains the value of an address which is no longer valid), but `str` still contains the contents "yay".

Comment: oh I get it. So I defined "yay" as `char* str = "yay"` instead, and now it worked. Thanks!

Comment: The `char hello[] = "hello";` needs to be `static char hello[] = "hello";`

Comment: You're accidentally printing out `str`, which you never changed, instead of `str_ptr` which you attempted to change.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void change_ptr(const char ** str_ptr)
{
  *str_ptr = "hello";
}

int main()
{
  char str[] = "yay";
  const char * str_ptr = str;
  const char ** ptr_to_str_ptr = &str_ptr;
  change_ptr(ptr_to_str_ptr);
  printf("%s\n", str_ptr);
}
```

Note that the string "hello" in this example is read-only because it is a string literal.  I added `const` in a few places so you are reminded of this and the compiler will warn you if you try to write to the string.  The pointer `str_ptr` can be modified, but not the string itself.